# Как в Apache создавать субдомены?

Tags: windows, apache

подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно создавать поддомены в Apache.
Что было сделано. Есть домен на рег ру, есть внешний статический ip. В настройках рег ру, были добавлены записи с основным доменом и субдомены, указан внешний ip.

- mysite.ru внешний ip
- subdomain.mysite.ru внешний ip.

В настройках апача были созданы виртуальные хосты, нужные папки, указаны пути, но.
Апач отдает сайт только по mysite.ru, если я ввожу в адресную строку subdomain.mysite.ru апач отдает 404 страницу.
Сервер виндовый, апач соотвественно тоже. Уже перечитал кучу информации. И не могу понять в чем дело.
Прикладываю часть конфига httpd-vhost

```
#Default roots
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@yandex.ru
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/www/mysite.ru/"
    ServerName mysite.ru
    ServerAlias www.mysite.ru
    
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@yandex.ru
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/www/mysite.ru/"
    ServerName mysite.ru
    ServerAlias www.mysite.ru
    
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
    SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/certs/mysite.ru/mysite.ru.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/certs/mysite.ru/mysite.ru.key"
</VirtualHost>

#Subdomains

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@yandex.ru
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/www/sumdomain.mysite.ru/"
    ServerName sumdomain.mysite.ru
    ServerAlias www.sumdomain.mysite.ru
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@yandex.ru
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/www/sumdomain.mysite.ru/"
    ServerName sumdomain.mysite.ru
    ServerAlias www.sumdomain.mysite.ru

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
    SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/certs/sumdomain.mysite.ru/sumdomain.mysite.ru.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/certs/sumdomain.mysite.ru/sumdomain.mysite.ru.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Давайте начнём с очевидного и глупого, но очень важного вопроса: каталог `"${SRVROOT}/htdocs/www/sumdomain.mysite.ru/"` вообще существует ли и содержит ли хоть что-нибудь?

Comment: Ну и вторая очевидная вещь — почитайте, что написано в логе ошибок по поводу 404

Comment: @andreymal ругается что этой папки нет, но она есть а в папке лежит index.html. Или я где то протупил или просто мистика происходит..

Comment: Значит внимательно проверьте пути на наличие опечаток, в частности что не перепутаны английская `c` и русская `с`

Comment: @andreymal разобрался, видимо и правда символы попутал. Спасибо. Сделайте ответ я отмечу решением. Еще раз спасибо за помощь.